# After website migration a year ago, some URLs from the old domain are still in Google. Should I block the old domain now?

Tags: seo, redirects, google-index, multiple-domains

I had an old domain which was migrated to a new domain. However, for a few pages redirects are not working properly and still being indexed in results.

The migration was done a year ago.

Would it be wise to block the old domain through robots.txt or remove the URLs from link removal tool in GWT?

Comment: Why not fix the redirects? Otherwise, if there is no value in the old domain why not just empty it? You can certainly use robots.txt. It seems to me that if you are willing to block with robots.txt then simply deleting the content or even the domain would be the same. If the old domain has value, I am thinking in terms of links, then fix the redirects. Cheers!!

Comment: Do these old pages on the old domain still return a valid resource? Why is there no catch-all redirect? And when you say "still being indexed in results" - is this the result of an organic search or a `site:` search?

Answer (score 3):

The best option would be to redirect those pages to respective pages on the new domain.

And notify Google using the change of address tool:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en

Now, since you did the migration about a year ago and if you are happy with your current ranking then you may delete the old domain.

I wouldn't recommend blocking using robots.txt or URL removal tool.

If you can redirect to the respective pages then do that. If hard then let it go to 404 as Google might have signal about the move.